# gtk# FileChooserDialog hangs in linux when calling the Destroy() method

Tags: c#, linux, gtk#

Im trying to get the path to a certain file to use it in an upload procedure and it works fine on Windows but whenever i try to use any linux based operating system when i click on the button to choose/save the file the dialog hangs but the application under still works as intended.
Moreover if i try to open a new file dialog it closes the one hanging and opens a  brand new working one

This is the code that handles the open file dialog

```
public string OpenFileDialog()
{
    Application.Init();

    FileChooserDialog file = new FileChooserDialog("Open file", null, FileChooserAction.Open);
    file.AddButton(Stock.Cancel, ResponseType.Cancel);
    file.AddButton(Stock.Ok, ResponseType.Ok);
    file.DefaultResponse = Gtk.ResponseType.Ok;
    file.SelectMultiple = false;

    Gtk.ResponseType response = (Gtk.ResponseType)file.Run();
    if (response == Gtk.ResponseType.Ok)
    {
        string file_path = file.Filename;
        //god help the soul of whoever finds this
        file_name = file.Filename.Substring(file.Filename.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        file.Destroy();
        return file_path;
    }
    else
    {
        file.Destroy();
        return "";
    }
}
```

and this is the one that handles the saving file dialog

```
public string SaveFileDialog(string filename_ftp)
{
    Application.Init();

    FileChooserDialog file = new FileChooserDialog("Open file", null, FileChooserAction.Save);
    file.AddButton(Stock.Cancel, ResponseType.Cancel);
    file.AddButton(Stock.SaveAs, ResponseType.Ok);
    file.DefaultResponse = Gtk.ResponseType.Ok;
    file.SelectMultiple = false;
    file.CurrentName = filename_ftp;
    Gtk.ResponseType response = (Gtk.ResponseType)file.Run();
    if (response == Gtk.ResponseType.Ok)
    {
        string file_path = file.Filename;
        //same as above
        file_name = file.Filename.Substring(file.Filename.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        file.Destroy();
        return file_path;
    }
    else
    {
        file.Destroy();
        return "";
    }
}
```

I was excpecting a behaviour similar to windows where it opens and closes correctly